# Microsoft word document hidden table

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document that has a lot of white space on the bottom of one page. It may be a hidden table. I've done all I can to try and remove it but I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more information. I would be glad to help you, but I need more information to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**- Enable the Paragraph Marks**

From the 'Home' tab turn on the 'Paragraph Marks" then try to move the table around 
 [image: Paragraph marks]

if "Paragrph Marks" isn't enough try to :

**- Enable Grid Lines**

1. Create any new table
2. click on the table you just created you will notice a new tab for formatting and controlling tables.
3. Open the 'Layout" tab
4. Click on "Grid Lines"

[image: Enabling Grid Lines]